# Auto Clicker Not Turning Off

Tags: python

I'm making a auto clicker which turns off and on with "e" but after
it turns on it doesn't turn off.

I've tried changing the code multiple times but still can't find out the
problem.

```py
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()


def onoff(keycode, on=None):
    rkey = str(keycode).strip("'")
    if rkey == "e":
        if not on:
            print("on")
            on = True
        elif on:
            print("off")
            on = False
    if not on:
        print("not on")
    elif on:
        while on:
            mouse.click(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.4)


with Listener(on_press=onoff) as l:
    l.join()
```

I expected it to turn off after I press "e" but keeps clicking.

Comment: I haven't used pynput before but, couldn't it be that it never exits that "while on" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you mean, because `Listener` in pynput is a new `thread`. If you need to stop this thread, the while True task in the thread will stop accordingly. All of them should be separated from each other. Use `.join()` method to turn off keyboard listen after second press "e" and keeps clicking, try the following code to see if you want the effect：

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
import threading

mouse = Controller()


class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_list = []
        self.c = threading.Thread(target=self.click)
        self.l = Listener(on_press=self.onoff)
        self.l.start()
        self.l.join()

    def click(self):
        while True:
            mouse.click(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.4)

    def onoff(self, key):
        try:
            key_str = key.char
        except AttributeError:
            key_str = key.name

        if key_str == "e":
            if len(self.key_list) == 0:
                self.key_list.append(key_str)
                self.c.start()
            elif key_str in self.key_list:
                self.l.stop()
                print('Keyboard listen stopped')
                print('Mouse click continue')
                self.c.join()


Demo()
```